# How to delete lines that are drawn in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, graphics2d

I've been doing a program that will paint lines in a `JLabel` with picture. after creating those lines, I want to delete those lines that I've drawn. For example, I want to delete the

```
d.drawLine(label.getGraphics(), 120,215,330,120);
```

Comment: Give us a chance: Provide the code for drawing your lines, as well as the code where you are trying to delete these lines.

Comment: Never use getGraphics() to do painting. That is only temporary. Custom painting is done in the paintComponent() method.

Answer (score 4):

Drawing does not work like that. Once you draw a line, it no longer exists as a line, just as a bunch of pixels that aren't functionally different from all the other pixels. There are however possible workarounds:

1. Redraw the line using the background colour (e.g. white). This only works if the line doesn't cover anything.
2. Make a `Line` class and keep a list of them. When you want to delete a line, remove it from the list, clear all lines, and then redraw all the lines in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete anything on a GUI. All you can do is keep writing over the top of what's there.  If you want to change a black line back to a white background, you can write a white line over the top.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing a canvas type implementation (Java) with a graphics DOM tree type implementation (SVG in browsers, for example).

In a DOM implementation you can remove the element and have the application work out what is the dirty region and to repaint any elements that have sections that fall within that dirty region (usually a rectangle).

In a canvas implementation like Java, you paint directly to a graphics object and once you've painted, the canvas doesn't know where you painted. Generally, you need to implement a mechanism to work out what is dirty and repaint your component in the affected areas. Such a mechanism is known a [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph).

Answer (score 1):

```
label.revalidate();
label.repaint();
```

...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { do not draw lines but the rest }
```

Drawing happens event based, so you put your drawing code into paintComponent or paint.
The redrawing can be triggered i.a. with a repaint.